# How to Hide a Web Part on SharePoint Modern Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I want to hide a webpart on SharePoint modern site? Can anyone help? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Which web part exactly? Is this a SharePoint out of the box web part or custom/SPFx web part? You want to hide it from all users or from specific users? You need to add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that modern SharePoint offers that setting out of the box. When you add a web part to a page, then it's visible. If you don't want to see it, you need to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you may need to inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions to hide the web part you want:

https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

Comment: This would not be a supported customisation and is not recommended by Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages